# Tensorflow - mask tensor element with condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors, one is 3d tensor with shape`[batch_size, timestep, feature]`, another one is 2d tensor with shape`[batch_size, timestep]`

eg.

```
data = tf.constant([[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]], dtype=tf.float32) # shape=(2, 3, 2)
mask = tf.constant([[True, True, False], [False, True, True]]) # shape=(2, 3)
```

and I would want to adapt the mask to the data

```
#Desired output (mask timestep with value -1)
[[[0, 0], [1, 1], [-1, -1]], [[-1, -1], [4, 4], [5, 5]]]
```

Are there any solutions with tensorflow build-in function or other workarounds to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use `tf.tile()` operation to expand the mask:

```
data = tf.constant([[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]], dtype=tf.float32)
mask = tf.constant([[True, True, False], [False, True, True]])

mask_expand = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1), multiples=[1,1, tf.shape(data)[-1]])

minus_ones = tf.fill(tf.shape(data), tf.constant(-1, dtype=data.dtype))
data = tf.where(mask_expand, data, minus_ones)
```

Comment: It looks more in line with TF style than my answer. But I have an another question, is it different between creating a `minus_ones` tensor of the same size as `data` (your method) and creating a `tf.constant` (my method) in `tf.where()`?

Comment: Also, there is a typo `mask_exp` / `mask_expand`

Comment: I've fixed the type, thanks! The `minus_one` approach works in all tensorflow versions. The `tf.constant` works in tensorflow_2.0 and doesn't work in tensorflow_1.12 for example.

Answer (score 1):

I do a simple workaround (change the shape of mask), maybe there is a better method, but I can't figure out now.

```
# reshape mask to the same shape with data
batch_size, total_timestep, feature_dimension = tf.shape(data)

# mask = [[[True], [True], [False]], [[False], [True], [True]]]
mask = tf.reshape(mask, [batch_size, total_timestep, 1]) # shape=(2, 3, 1)
# mask = [[[True, True], [True, True], [False, False]], [[False, False], [True, True], [True, True]]]
mask = tf.broadcast_to(mask, [batch_size, total_timestep, feature_dimension]) # shape=(2, 3, 2)

# adapt mask
data = tf.where(mask, data, tf.constant(-1, dtype=data.dtype) )
```